# How can I prevent a query with a url in it being recognized as a folder name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, request

I have a program that makes specific documents based off of requested sites. My static frontend makes a request to my backend (express), including the URL as a parameter in the query of the URL, like this:

```
https://my-backend.dev/request?url=https://google.com
```

However, the browser recognises my request as this:

```
my-backend.dev
  Folder: request?url=https:
    Folder:
      Page: google.com
```

and it shows up as a 404 page, because I am actually requesting

```
my-backend.dev
 Page:request
   Query:
     url: https://google.com
```

What should I do? drop the HTTPS and test which one works in my code?

EDIT:

I tried using params (/request/:URL), but now it gave me an error saying:

```
Cannot GET /testfvc/https:/google.com
```

I also notice that when I put in double slashes, chrome automatically makes them into a single slash.

Comment: I'm pretty sure browser doesn't care about what is after domain name. Server gets everything and parses it. I guess that the problem is somewhere else

Comment: "What should I do?" Encode the url after the `?` perhaps?

Comment: I tested it by using no params, with URL being https:google.com, and it worked (well at least no 404 it said failed request to https:google.com)

Comment: well I want to set this up as a API too, and nobody is going to encode a URL, and then send it to my backend

Comment: What if you do this? ```https://my-backend.dev/request?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com```

Comment: have you tried to put it between quotes so its considered a string ? `https://my-backend.dev/request?url="https://google.com"`

also you need to escape the ?#& if you want to pass url with params such as & => %26, check :
encodeURIComponent('https://google.com?test="http://url.com?id=999');
outputs:
"https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%3Ftest%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Furl.com%3Fid%3D999"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: The browser sends the URL to the server as in the request, unless there is a ServiceWorker in the middle that modifies it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `req.query` object for query string parameters:

```
router.get("/request", (req, res) => {
   const site = req.query.url;
   console.log("The site is", site);
   // ....

});
```

The request submitted should be appropriately url-encoded.